# Keywords "and", "or" and "not" not defined

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I'm working on a C++ project on Visual Studio 2008 and I found out that `and`, `not` and `or` keywords are not defined.

Am I missing some configuration to enable the use of theses keywords?
AFAIK, they are part of the standard, no?

Comment: Do you mean && ! and ||

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"Include the header file iso646.h, or compile with the /Za (Disable language extensions) compiler option."*

[**MSDN Link**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6s3h5a7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Note that `iso646.h` is deprecated and you should use `ciso646` instead. However, seeing as how you shouldn't need to include the header in the first place, maybe `ciso646` is broken, too. I don't know.